# Implementation of Line Drawing Algorithm doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, bgi, bresenham

First question, I have tried to calculate the expression, `di+1=di+2*Δy−2*Δx(yi+1−yi)` for the four quadrants. Irrespective of the quadrant, the expression was found to be the same, including signs.
Am I right, or, there has been some mistakes in my calculations (hence, I am wrong)?

Second question, if this expression is only applicable for the first octet, how can I apply this to other octets? To me, there is no way to determine which octet I am working on. Coz, the value of m always represent two opposite octets. For example, if `0<m<1`, it represents 1st and 5th octet. Right?

Thirdly, how can we determine the initial/starting value of di?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utils.h"

void BresenhamLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, int color)
{
    if(x1>x2 || y1>y2)
    {
        Swap(x1, x2);
        Swap(y1, y2);
    }
    double x = x1;
    double y = y1;
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    double dt = 2 * (dy - dx);
    double ds = 2 * dy;
    double d = 2*dy - dx;

    PlotPixel(x, y, color);

    if(dx>=dy)
    {
        while(x<=x2)
        {
            x++;
            if(d<0)
            {
                d = d + ds;
            }
            else
            {
                y++;
                d = d + dt;
            }
            PlotPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(y<=y2)
        {
            y++;
            if(d<0)
            {
                x++;
                d = d + dt;
            }
            else
            {               
                d = d + ds;
            }
            PlotPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
int gm = DETECT;
int gd = DETECT;

initgraph(&gm, &gd, "");

double x1 = 0;
double y1 = 0;
double r = 50;
double x2 = 0;
double y2 = 0;
double signx = 0;
double signy = 0;

for(int theta=0 ; theta<=360 ; theta++)
{
    x2 = r * cos(DegreeToRad((double) theta));
    y2 = r * sin(DegreeToRad((double) theta));

    x1 = 5 * cos(DegreeToRad((double) theta));
    y1 = 5 * sin(DegreeToRad((double) theta));

    BresenhamLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, YELLOW);
}

getch();
closegraph();
return 0;
}
```

The lines that go through 2nd and 4th quadrant are not showing up.

How to fix that with some minor changes in my code?

Comment: Maybe saying it is your implementation that isn't working, rather than the algorithm, would be more accurate?  ;)

Comment: Work through your implementation on paper. Compare it with the real algorithm. Find the bug. We are not a bug-hunting service.

Comment: why this `-100 100 -100 100`?

Comment: @perreal, actually, I was changing the signs like binary number. 0101. Nothing important.

Comment: Please explain clearly what you have vaguely summarized by " Irrespective of the quadrant, the expression was found to be the same, including signs."

Comment: Bresenham is notable for using only INTEGER arithmetic. If you have floating point hardware, you do not need Bresenham. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this input: `x1: 100 y1: -100 x2: -100 y2: 100`

this logic:

```
if(x1>x2 || y1>y2)
{   
    Swap(x1, x2);
    Swap(y1, y2);
}
```

fails.

Comment: handle magnitude and direction separately

Answer (score 1):

This page is a good place to start. It shows code as well for 1 of the octants:

http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html

I think you need to swap the `x` if `x1 > x2` and swap the `y` if `y1 > y2` but not swap *both* if only 1 of those is true.

The *external links* section of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) contains several links to ready-made implementations that you can study.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void BresenhamLine( double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, int color )
{
  const bool steep = (std::abs(y2 - y1) > std::abs(x2 - x1));
  if(steep)
  {
    std::swap(x1, y1);
    std::swap(x2, y2);
  }

  if(x1 > x2)
  {
    std::swap(x1, x2);
    std::swap(y1, y2);
  }

  double dx = x2 - x1;
  double dy = std::abs(y2 - y1);

  double error = dx / 2;
  int ystep = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;
  int y = (int)y1;

  int maxX = (int)x2;

  for(int x=(int)x1; x<maxX; x++)
  {
    if(steep)
    {
        PlotPixel(y, x, color);
    }
    else
    {
        PlotPixel(x, y, color);
    }

    error -= dy;
    if(error < 0)
    {
        y += ystep;
        error += dx;
    }
  }
}
```

I got this by slightly modifying the code here:http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#C.2B.2B

Comment: Ok. It works. But, I was talking about some minor modification of my code so that I can understand the theory.

Comment: then mainly you need to change `if(x1>x2 || y1>y2) { Swap(x1, x2); Swap(y1, y2); }` into `if(x1>x2) Swap(x1, x2); if(y1>y2) Swap(y1, y2);`